# Why am I getting table does not exist error?

Tags: postgresql

so I'm trying to creating a database table using pg admin. I created a table in pg admin and then I was supposed to run the table using putty. But when I run it it says error table does not exist. The table does exist though so I don't know why I'm getting that error!

```
--Dropping tables clear out any existing data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS automobiles;

CREATE TABLE automobiles(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    owner CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    msrp DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    purchase_date DATE NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO automobiles(id, make, model, year, owner, msrp, purchase_date) VALUES(
    1,
    'Ferarri',
    'F40',
    '1987',
    '',
    '1690000',
    '3/12/2019');
INSERT INTO automobiles(id, make, model, year,owner, msrp, purchase_date)VALUES(
    2,
    'Tundra',
    '4X2',
    '2019',
    '',
    '39625',
    '3/12/2019');
INSERT INTO automobiles(id, make, model, year,owner, msrp, purchase_date) VALUES(
    3,
    'Mercedes-Benz',
    'AMG GT',
    '2014',
    '',
    '145000',
    '3/12/2019');
INSERT INTO automobiles(id, make, model, year,owner, msrp, purchase_date)VALUES(
    4,
    'Chrysler',
    '300',
    '2004',
    '',
    '800',
    '3/12/2019');
INSERT INTO automobiles(id, make, model, year,owner, msrp, purchase_date) VALUES(
    5,
    'Jeep',
    'Wrangler',
    '2019',
    '',
    '33695',
    '3/12/2019');

SELECT make, model, year, msrp FROM automobiles ORDER BY year ASC;

UPDATE automobiles
SET owner = 'Deanna Slotegraaf'
WHERE make = 'ferarri';

DELETE FROM automobiles WHERE make = 'Chrysler';
```

This is the full set of code that I have.

```
Last login: Mon Mar 11 18:02:19 2019 from 108.170.191.53
slotegraafd@opentech:~$ cd /var/www/html/webd2201/slotegraafd/sql
slotegraafd@opentech:/var/www/html/webd2201/slotegraafd/sql$ psql -d slotegraafd_db -f lab7_auto_records.sql
Password:
psql:lab7_auto_records.sql:9: NOTICE:  table "automobiles" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
psql:lab7_auto_records.sql:30: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "3/12/2019"
LINE 8:  '3/12/2019');
         ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
psql:lab7_auto_records.sql:38: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "3/12/2019"
LINE 8:  '3/12/2019');
         ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
psql:lab7_auto_records.sql:46: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "3/12/2019"
LINE 8:  '3/12/2019');
         ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
psql:lab7_auto_records.sql:54: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "3/12/2019"
LINE 8:  '3/12/2019');
         ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
psql:lab7_auto_records.sql:62: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "3/12/2019"
LINE 8:  '3/12/2019');
         ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
 make | model | year | msrp
------+-------+------+------
(0 rows)

UPDATE 0
DELETE 0
```

This is the putty session

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "run the table using putty"? May be you could copy/paste the session where you "run the table".

Comment: basically running it through a terminal i just edited the question and pasted the putty session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table isn't missing. The message "*table "automobiles" does not exist, skipping*" stems from the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` statement and just informs you that there wasn't such a table to be dropped.

If you look at the message it starts with `NOTICE:` which tells you that it's **not** an error. Error messages start with `ERROR:` (as you can see later on in your script)

Your table was successfully created.

---

However, your INSERTs are failing as you are providing the values for the date column in the wrong format. The most robust way to supply a date constant is to use the ANSI SQL syntax for dates: `DATE '2018-03-12'`, so your inserts should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO automobiles(id, make, model, year, owner, msrp, purchase_date) 
VALUES
(   1,
    'Ferarri',
    'F40',
    '1987',
    '',
    '1690000',
    DATE '2019-03-12'), 
(   2,
    'Tundra',
    '4X2',
    '2019',
    '',
    '39625',
    DATE '2019-03-12'), 
...;
```

If you don't like the ISO formatted date literals, you can also use the `to_date()` function instead: `to_date('3/12/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')`.

---

The message

> ```
> date/time field value out of range: "3/12/2019"
> LINE 8:  '3/12/2019');
>          ^
> HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
> ```

suggests to change the `DateStyle` setting in order to allow the *implicit* conversion of a string value like `'3/12/2019'` to a proper date.

I strongly discourage the use of the `DateStyle` parameter as that makes your SQL statements dependent on the environment and they might still fail when run on a different computer.